# How do you loop multple iterations using variables from CSV file?

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I am trying to run the following in iterations pulling VAR1 and VAR2 from a CSV file called sample.csv and inserting them into the matching spots below and looping the function for each row in the CSV file.

```
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("a.b.com")
payload = json.dumps({
  "node_list": [
    {
      "id": VAR1,
      "with_descendants": True
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'A'
}
conn.request("PUT", "/poweruser/v1/powerusers/VAR2/branches?access_token=xyz", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Sample.csv:

VAR1,VAR2
10,20
30,40
50,60
70,80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv` module to parse the lines.

```py
with open('sample.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # this is to skip the first line in the csv file
    for VAR1, VAR2 in reader:
        print(f"A code with VAR1={VAR1}, and VAR2={VAR2}")
```

Replace the print statement with your code.

Comment: `csv.reader(file.readlines()[1:])` -> `csv.reader(file)`

Comment: Except for the first line. I have `[1:]` on purpose to skip the first line, which I understood is "VAR1,VAR2", not actual values that we want to process. But perhaps I misunderstood the question — silentmyst, if the first line should also be processed, use juanpa's suggestion.

Comment: then do `next(reader)`. The problem with readlines (aside from the fact that this method is outdated, you should just use `list(file)` not `file.readlines()`), is that it *reads the whole file into memory*, instead, you want to lazily iterate line by line if possible

Comment: Aha, I see, I will edit the answer. Thanks for the clarification! I didn't realise that `file.readlines()` is the same as `list(file)`, I thought it was reading line by line from the file.